# What / Where is the default Spark on Yarn Working directory?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

When working on standalone, the working directory is basically $SPARK_HOME/work.

However i have no idea how to find that when working in Yarn mode ? Can someone else me find the working directory for spark or maybe application running on yarn ?

Answer (score 1):

The default value is always `$SPARK_HOME/work`.

If you want a specific working directory please configure `SPARK_WORKER_DIR` environment variable, for example using `conf/spark-env.sh`

Comment: This is strange. My working directory seems to be on hdfs and i don't know why ? Any Idea ?

Comment: @MaatDeamon Well, you should probably set it to a local directory. Are you sure you're not using an old `$SPARK_HOME/conf/spark-defaults.com` or `$SPARK_HOME/conf/spark-env.sh`?

Answer (score 0):

when spark run on yarn, the work dir locate at {yourYarnLocalDir}/usercache/{yourUserName}/appcache/{yourApplicationId}